# Duplicate entry mysql

Tags: mysql, primary-key, duplicates

I have a table which has does not have a primary key.Table has some indexes. Whenever I try to insert record for the  first time ,record gets inserted successfully but when i try to insert record with same value again it gives  Duplicate entry '125249-1'.
Create table :-

```
CREATE TABLE `schedules` (
  `entity` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `applicationid` int(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `apptnid` int(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `apptorgunitid` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `orgid` int(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nid` int(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `logged_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `logged_by` int(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_updated_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_updated_by` int(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rowstate` int(8) DEFAULT '1',
  `status` int(16) DEFAULT '1',
   KEY `applicationid` (`applicationid`),
  KEY `apptnid` (`apptnid`),
  KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

insert into schedules (entity, id, applicationid, apptnid, apptorgunitid, orgid, nid, logged_date, logged_by,  rowstate, status) values (125249,454,85246,2,2,124,1,current_timestamp,9999,1,1)

Error : - Duplicate entry '125249-1' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Comment: Does not look like you have a primary key in the table definition, check if there is some trigger associated for this table which is executing `after insert` or check if you are in the correct database. And if `entity` is primary key you can not have same value again in the table.

Comment: Table  doesnot have any primary key .Still it giving Duplicate entry '125249-1' for key 'PRIMARY'  error.

Comment: I have tried it on sqlfiddle.com and it is not reproduceable. Is it possible that you drop the table, recreate it and try it again? or du you have some stored procedures in your db?

Comment: @ABC . . . I can think of two possible reasons.  (1) You are connected to a different database when you run the `insert`.  (2) You have a trigger on the table that, in turn, inserts into another table that does have a primary key.